# Setting the data model in pandas

Tags: pandas, etl

So I'm used to database ETL. In SQL I Create the table and set the char lengths, data types etc. As I understand it pandas uses the max length of whatever is put into the dataframe. Fine if you're staying in python, but I need to specify these things explicitly.

Here's some base code to work from, pointers welcome:

```
df=pd.Dataframe()
df['ID'] = some data probably i + 1
df['text'] = some text length set to max 255
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an informative article on pandas datatypes:
https://pbpython.com/pandas_dtypes.html

If you want to see the datatypes of your dataframe, you can do:

```
df.info()
```

You can set datatypes explicitly where you can choose to ignore or raise errors with [.astype()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].astype(int, errors='raise')
df['ID'] = df['ID'].astype(int, errors='ignore')
```

For strings you can set the datatype as follows:

```
df['text'] = df['text'].astype('string')
```

Or if you're using an older version of pandas < 1.0 then do:

```
df['text'] = df['text'].astype(str)
```

If you want to set a max length for your string, you could do:

```
df['text'] = df['text'].str.slice(0, 255)
```

Comment: I'm not sure this last part makes sense, this would simply truncate all existing data within the `df['text']` column, rather than enforce that data entered into this column could not exceed `255` chars in length. I'm not sure if the latter is possible in pandas, but that's what I think the OP is inquiring about (I might be wrong though).

Comment: @baxx agree, but I wonder if there's a way to set max length of a string column in advance

Comment: not afaik :/ (which doesn't mean it's not), to be clear I don't know any better than your answer, just felt it worth highlighting that this might be a limitation (and that OP's request might not be possible using pandas). Unless one builds a custom class or something based on pandas / monkey patches it or something along those lines (which would be interesting to see)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I'll be converting the pandas df to geopandas, adding some geometry. I'll export it to a shapefile format and the client has set certain criteria for lengths of fields, I was hoping there would be someway to set the data model, like Django does. Otherwise I have some major editing to do outside of python 3.x.